# CSS3 change div style

Tags: html, css

i have searched over an hour right now after this. Im trying to find how to style a div's apperance.

http://i.gyazo.com/b3e39c4d80c74e559e832c4d22bb87c2.png

The picture show a black div with a "arrow" side on the left. How do you make those things?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll find something here. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css3+arrow

Comment: Or here : https://www.google.com/search?q=css3+triangle&oq=css3+triangle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1837j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

here is a quick way to accomplish this.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/g9m1w55v/3/)

css

```
#frame{
    width:90%;
    border: 20px solid lightblue;
    background:black;
}
.title{
    font-size:3em;
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    top: 60px;
    margin-left:80px;
}
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

    border-left: 60px solid lightblue;
}
```

html

```
<div id="frame">
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
<div class="title">Some text here!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an inverted arrow (border hacks using top and bottom border) to achieve this.  You can also make it part of a pseudo-element so that your markup remains clean.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:200);
body {
    background: #BCDEB1;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    float:right;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    line-height: 1em;

    margin-right: 0.1em;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

h1:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border: 0 solid black;
    border-left: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-top-width: 1em;
    border-bottom-width: 1em; /* 1 + 1 = 2.  The parent is 1em line height + 0.5em top padding + 0.5em bottom padding */
    
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<h1>Administration and etc?</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the triangle is angled, it may be worth looking into SVG as the `content`  of a `:before` pseudo element.

Here is a codepen that I almost completed for you using only CSS. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPVERJ

You may have to tweak it a bit to get it looking exactly like the image.
I used [cssarrowplease](http://cssarrowplease.com/) to generate the basic arrow and tweaked it from there.

Also see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

I would google something like this before asking here, this is a problem that has been figured out many times over.